# Could micro-states not have equal probability as assumed?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, multiverse

How could micro-states have uniform distribution in a 3D space unless there was 0 Gravity? Gravity violates the assumption of equal probability as it makes matter move in a predictable direction. Micro-states can be predicted. When not acted upon matter has 0 probability of going in "up" directions and 100% probability of going in "down" directions due to the order imposed upon matter by Gravity. You actually need to apply Force to stop matter from going in "down" directions. How does Entropy explain rivers with equal probability? Molecules in a river have an obvious order. How does order come from equal probability? Equal probability cannot exist as Gravity creates a bias which cannot be ignored.
As I see it time arrow decreases "uniform distribution or disorder" as matter is being arranged in "an order by Gravity" using Bubble sort method.
During a free fall matter does not get Bubble sorted as all matter falls at the same rate, so time arrow stops in a free fall. 
In short,
Gravity creates a bias which is present through out the universe hence equal probability cannot exist in the universe for neither matter nor light under any circumstances.

If equal probability does not exist then that means Entropy, Statistical Mechanics, Thermodynamic equilibrium, Evolution and Multiverse etc are invalid and misleading.
TE remains unproven too for that reason.
Hence it is pertinent that Entropy assumption should be checked to ensure if it is true or not. I believe it is a false assumption. Equal probability if assumed true tend to be self-fulfilling as every order can be assigned a certain probability if equal probability is assumed.
Does equal probability really exist or not? I don't think it does. It cannot. If you think it does or can, then how? What about the bias Gravity imposes on matter? How can equal probability and bias co-exist? Equal probability cannot exit in presence of bias hence Entropy assumption is wrong.

P.S. Message has been edited as requested by mods.

Comment: A few things to note.  1) This sounds like total nonsense and that you are using scientific words without understanding the meaning.   Clarity goes a long way in sharing ideas.  2)  This is a question and answer site, not a chat forum where we enter into debates.  3)  This site deals with [mainstream physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site/4539#4539).  We are not here to evaluate your theories, but instead to help educate each other in the currently accepted mainstream theories.  This question is a poor fit for the site

Comment: I am asking to critically look at the assumption Entropy makes as I think it is false. And that is why it has never been proven to be true.

Comment: Ok, I will re-word so you can understand the point I am trying to make better. I do have a question about the assumption Entropy makes which I would like explained if possible.

Answer (score 3):

> As per my observation, Micro-states do no have equal probability

Statistical mechanics doesn't say that all microstates have equal probability in the first place. It postulates: **all microstates *compatible with a given macrostate* are equally probable**. Microstates that are associated with *different* macrostates can have different probabilities of occurring. For example, for a gas in a perfectly insulating box with total energy $E$, volume $V$, and number of particles $N$, any microstate which has total energy $E$, volume $V$, and number of particles $N$ has an equal (nonzero) probability of occurring. However, a microstate with a different total energy $E'\neq E$ has zero probability of occurring.

> and hence Entropy argument is invalid as it is standing on a wrong assumption.

Since you have assumed that statistical mechanics says something that it doesn't, this does not hold (nor is it clear what the "Entropy argument" is in the first place).

> In fact, micro states have 0 probability of going in "up" directions and 100% probability of going in "down" directions due to the order imposed upon matter by Gravity.

Microstates don't "go" anywhere. They are simply descriptions of possible configurations of the system. The *system* can "go" from one microstate to another over time, but the microstates themselves are like pins on a map - they just mark particular locations in phase space.

In any case, let's consider the situation you're talking about here. Suppose you have a collection of particles contained within a perfectly insulating box. Suppose they start out in zero gravity, distributed uniformly on average throughout the box, and suppose they are in thermal equilibrium, so that the particles have a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution in energy and momentum, distributed uniformly in direction of motion. The box has a particular macrostate (namely, it has a fixed total internal energy $E$, volume $V$, and total number of particles $N$), which is constant over time. Many, many different microstates are compatible with this microstate, with different temperatures, spatial distributions, momentum distributions, pressures, and so on. As time passes and the particles move around and collide with the walls, the system adopts many different microstates (one for each configuration that the particles adopt), and because of this, the temperature and pressure of the collection of particles, as well as the spatial arrangement and momentum of the particles in the box, are constantly fluctuating with time.

When we turn on gravity, what statistical mechanics tells us is that *eventually*, once the system has once again reached equilibrium, the system will once again be in one macrostate (not necessarily the same one), with constant total energy, volume, and particle number, and fluctuating pressure, temperature, and position and momentum of the particles in the box. The fact that the arrangement of particles within the box is fluctuating means that the particles *don't* necessarily have to constantly move down. In fact, individual particles are actually moving *upwards* at least some of the time (if they were constantly moving down, then the system wouldn't be in equilibrium).

> You actually need to apply Force to stop the micro-states from going in "down" directions.

Once again, microstates don't "go" anywhere. The system transitions between microstates because its internal components are constantly moving around; as we have already discussed, at equilibrium, they move around in ways that do not affect the macrostate. No external force is needed for this to happen.

> As I see it time arrow is moving in the direction of matter being arranged in an order by Gravity using Bubble sort method.

The "arrow of time" is simply a consequence of counting microstates. Namely, it's the idea that, for a given macrostate and for certain initial conditions, there are many, many more microstates compatible with that macrostate that *don't* resemble the initial conditions of a system than there are that *do*. As the system transitions between microstates, it's therefore very likely to transition to a state that doesn't resemble the initial conditions. Nowhere does this involve either gravity or the bubble sort method, nor is it clear how that would even apply here.

> During a free fall matter does not get Bubble sorted, so time arrow stops in a free fall.

Suppose you had a box with a removable wall inside it, with gas on one side and a vacuum on the other. Suppose you dropped that box while removing the wall. As the box falls, the gas would expand to fill the whole box. Therefore, the arrow of time still applies in free fall.

> A sand castle should never fall apart in free fall as all molecules would be moving in the same direction with the same speed.

All the sand grains may be moving together, but the atoms aren't (sand isn't really made of molecules, since it's a covalent network solid, so I'm going to assume that's what you meant). The sand castle is at a nonzero temperature, so the atoms are constantly vibrating in random directions around their position in the lattice of a sand grain. If you were to heat this sand castle enough before dropping it, the random vibrations would be strong enough to break the bonds holding the sand grains together, and as you dropped the sand castle, it would vaporize in free fall and fall apart.

> Entropy argument is built on an assumed Null Hypothesis (absence of order)

Since you never defined the "Entropy argument," this doesn't actually mean anything.

> Gravity destroys the Null hypothesis as it imposes an order on matter and arranges the matter in an order.

Gravity does not always make things more ordered. For example, if a small planet passes within the Roche limit of a large planet, gravity exerts strong enough tidal forces on the small planet to tear it apart, turning the system from a relatively ordered collection of matter (two planets) to a disordered system (one planet and billions of small planet fragments orbiting randomly around it).

> Micro states do not have equal probability of going in any direction as they are always gravitating or "flowing" in one direction under an order imposed upon them by Gravity.

Microstates themselves don't move. A system transitions between microstates. As previously discussed, the system can transition to any microstate compatible with its macrostate, including those that don't "flow" in the right direction. This is what makes certain quantities in a system (like temperature of a gas in a perfectly insulating box) fluctuate with time.

> As Gravity creates a bias which is present through out the universe hence equal probability does not exist in the universe for neither matter nor light.

The action of gravity influences *which* microstates are compatible with a given macrostate, but it does not change the fact that all microstates compatible with a given macrostate are equally probable.

For our gas-in-the-box example, consider a microstate where the total kinetic energy of the particles is slightly lower than $E$, but where the particles were generally near the top of the box. In zero gravity, this microstate would not have been compatible with the macrostate having energy $E$. But the addition of gravity means that gravitational potential energy must be accounted for; this means that the particles in the top of the box have some gravitational potential energy, which could raise the total energy of the gas to $E$. Therefore, this state *would* be compatible with the macrostate having energy $E$ when gravity is turned on. Over time, the system transitions between the microstates compatible with a given macrostate, including this one and many others (for example, one with the particles lower in the box but with higher total kinetic enerhgy), all of them being equally probable as long as they're compatible with the macrostate of the gas in the box.

> If equal probability does not exist and it doesn't

You have not shown this. You have argued against a version of physics that doesn't exist.

> then that means Entropy, Statistical Mechanics, Thermodynamic equilibrium, Evolution and Multiverse etc argument are completely invalid too.

Your premise is false, so the conclusion does not follow.

> Wouldn't you agree?

No.

> I thought one had to prove "equal probability or absence of order (Null hypothesis)" first before one could build hypothesis on it.

Statistical mechanics has described how the world works exceedingly well, within its region of applicability, which is why we are confident in the validity of the postulates underpinning it.

> How did Boltzmann even get his paper published?

Without knowing which paper you're talking about, it's not particularly clear how to answer this. In general, though, Boltzmann created novel models that accurately described the behavior of systems of large numbers of particles, advancing the field of statistical mechanics. This is precisely the kind of material that constitutes a paper.

> It is a fatal flaw to build on an assumed Null hypothesis as one, Null is rarely ever true and two you have to show evidence of a negative systematic search to claim absence of all discernible order and only then you can build your argument.

You have not actually explained what the "assumed Null hypothesis" is, so it's not entirely clear what you're objecting to. That said, if the "assumed Null hypothesis" is that microstates compatible with a given macrostate are equally probable, then we use it as a postulate because it generates a model that produces results that make sense and accurately describe the behavior of systems of large numbers of objects. In short, it works better than anything else we've found and it's logically consistent, which is why we use the model.

> If you do an inadequate search then someone else may find the order you failed to find. It will not only invalidate your arguments but also could be somewhat embarrassing.

If someone were to demonstrate that another theory, based on different assumptions, unequivocally gave more correct predictions than statistical mechanics over its entire range of applicability, then we would start using that new theory instead. The discovery of that theory would be heralded as ushering in a new era of statistical mechanics. It wouldn't be "embarrassing," it would be a triumph of the scientific method.

Of course, we could still use ordinary statistical mechanics if the difference between its predictions and the predictions of the new theory were too small for us to care about in a particular regime, and we probably would do exactly that if statistical mechanics turned out to be computationally simpler to work with. This is exactly what has happened with Newtonian gravity; general relativity gives more correct predictions, but computationally it's much more difficult, and the difference between the predictions of Newtonian gravity and general relativity are miniscule in all but the most extreme situations, so we still use Newtonian gravity for simple, rough calculations of orbital dynamics.

> That is why no one builds on assumed Null hypothesis these days.

If you're trying to say that nobody trusts statistical mechanics these days, there are quite a lot of engineers who would disagree with you.

> Why didn't scientists confirm monotheisms claims of "all matter having an invisible Lord who created the stars with his order" defeats me.

Because this model does not make any testable predictions about how the universe behaves.

> A God could have been proven scientifically at least 400 years ago IMO.

See above.

> Let's have a debate and reason.

This is a question-and-answer site, not a forum for debate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91382/discussion-on-answer-by-probably-someone-could-micro-states-not-have-equal-proba).